# How to get output of wvdial with ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, ubuntu, processbuilder

Code below prints output of executing process (using different thread for output):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
        IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("some_command");
    final Process process = builder.start();
    final Thread ioThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    ioThread.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
```

So, if I run this code with

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("ping","8.8.8.8");
```

output will be like this:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=205 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=202 ms
...
```

But if I run

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("wvdial");
```

then command will be executed (wvdial will start) but there will be no output in `BufferedReader`. `wvdial` in terminal shows output text.

Why `wvdial` gives no output for `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: Have you checked the behavior of `wvdial` when no input is provided?

Comment: @fge do you mean no parameter case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it writes to `stderr`? `process.getErrorStream()`

Most UNIX programs avoid writing information messages for humans to `stdout`. Especially batch programs. `stdout` is for program results, for data output, not for informational messages.

You might also be able to make sense of exit code thus abolishing the need of output parsing.